# C# Bitmap class with matrix transformation (Shear method)

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, bitmap, coordinate-transformation

So I want to use the a matrix transformation with the bitmap class.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Shear(0.1f, 30);
```

But the only was I can do this is to use the graphics class

```
    FileStream ifs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\asd.png", FileMode.Open);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ifs);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    g.Transform = matrix;
```

But how can I use the graphics object with the bitmap.
I can do this             `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(750,500,g);`
but it seems that the graphics object doesn't really keep the pixels but only it's dimensions. Any suggestions how can I use the matrix's Shear method with the bitmaps (my image)?

Comment: Please read [ask], take the [tour] and make ample use of Google.  [C# How to: Image Transform Shear](https://softwarebydefault.com/2013/06/16/image-transform-shear/)

Comment: @Plutonix I read that one but the math behind it was very hard...

Comment: @Plutonix my question is basically how to use the matrix class with the bitmap class?

Comment: There is no math in [ask] or the [tour].  the example on MSDN works fine and shows how to use a Matrix for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get what you want (the shear transformation) when you DRAW something using your new Graphics object.

So if you just create a new bitmap and that draw your existing bitmap onto it using *DrawImage*, you're home.

Note that you'll have to calculate the expected size of the new bitmap yourself.